# binary operator implemented as a static member function

Tags: c++

so on my book it reads:

> The definition of a binary operator implemented as a global function or a **static** member function is the following:
>   `return_type operator_type (parameter1, parameter2);`

Now I don't understand what the author means by a

> static member function

How I understand it; It is an operator overload inside a class that is `static` which in my belief is not possible, I don't understand...

I can't do this:

```cpp
class Test {
//data attributes
public:
   static Date operator+(Date& lhs, Date& rhs) {
        //implementation code
    }
}
```

Because if I do that I get an error: `Overloaded 'operator+' cannot be a static member function`.

So is this an error or I misinterpreted it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# operators are static member functions, but in C++  (contrary to what your book states) they are either top-level(global) or non-static members of the class on the left-hand-side of the expression, `Date` in this case:

```
class Date {
//data attributes
public:
   Date operator+(const Date& rhs) const {
        //implementation code
    }
}
```

Note the two `const`s, since neither of the parameters to addition are changed by it.

Comment: So that means that it is an error and it should be : `non-static members` instead of `static member functions`?

Comment: Therefore could you specify that in response please.

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

#### Overloaded operator functions may not implemented a static member functions

If this is in fact a quotation from a C++ reference [**emphasis** mine]

> The definition of a binary operator implemented as a global function **or a static member function** is the following: [...]

then the emphasized part of this reference is wrong.

From [[over.oper]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.oper#6), covering *overloaded operators* [**emphasis** mine]:

> An operator function shall either be **a non-static member function** or
>   be a non-member function [...]

And, specifically, from [[over.binary]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.oper#over.binary-1), for overloading *binary operators* [**emphasis** mine]::

> A binary operator shall be implemented either by **a non-static member function** ([[class.mfct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct)) with one parameter or by a non-member function with two parameters.